# FileStream doesn't seem to get enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

On one of our Dev DBs I am trying to enable FileStream.

I ran the script below and it is says it went from 0 - Disabled to 2 - Enabled:

```
Use FileStreamTest
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'filestream access level', 2
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

But When I run this I get the error FILESTREAM is disabled?:

```
ALTER DATABASE FileStreamTest 
ADD FILEGROUP FS_FG_20110101
CONTAINS FILESTREAM
GO
```

Running this Shows a value of 2 (Enabled):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'filestream access level';
```

Error Message:

```
Msg 5591, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
FILESTREAM feature is disabled.
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Do I have to go into the SQL Server Configuration manager and change the properties on the MSSQLSERVER instance (service) as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you do need to enable file stream through SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Here is some more [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx).

Comment: For my case, I was missing the [Step 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), that's why it wasn't restoring.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server 2008 R2 it is necessary to restart the SQL server service after the reconfiguration even when you execute `RECONFIGURE` or `RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE`.

Proof:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'filestream access level';
```

returns the value for configuration setting 1580 "filestream access level" as 2 but value_in_use 1.

After a restart of the service, the problem goes away and there is one obstacle less on the winding road of FILESTREAM configuration.