# FILESTREAM feature is disabled.

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore a backup of database taken from sql server 2012. The destination system as sql serer 2017`(Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 16299: ) )`

But I am getting this error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Restore of database 'SITELINEDEV' failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: FILESTREAM feature is disabled. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17213.0+((SSMS_Rel).171128-2020)&LinkId=20476

Can you please suggest me solution to this?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550193/filestream-doesnt-seem-to-get-enabled

Answer (score 2):

Enable the filestream feature of your SQL 2017 instance and try the restore again.

One way to enable filestream is with SQL Server 2017 Configuration Manager (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc). Select SQL Server Services, right-click on the SQL Server service in the right pane, and select Properties. Click on the FILESTREAM tab and check the Enable FILESTREAM check boxes.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty confident you can't restore a .bak from a 2012 server to 2017. I'd recommend Generating Scripts for the database, and include both schema and data and run the generated scripts against your 2017 server.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-with-backup-and-restore?view=sql-server-2017) states "In SQL Server 2017, you can create a new database by restoring a backup of a user database created by using SQL Server 2005 or a later version".

Comment: Aw, hell, you're right mate. I'm thinking of the opposite scenario. My apologies. I've tried restoring 2016 .bak files to 2012 and that failed. Ignore me, I'm just trying to get enough rep to actually comment in this place.